# Javascript Recursive Decrement Index Increasing Output

Tags: javascript, math, recursion, iteration

So I have a function getNext, that takes one argument i.  The function needs to recursively iterate until i is 0.  However, in the function I need a set of numbers to increase from 2.

```
function getNext(i) {
    if(i == 0) return;
    console.log('index: ' + i);
    console.log( code_here );
    i--;
    getNext(i);
}
```

So the output of getNext(3) would be:

```
index: 3
2
index: 2
3
index: 1
4
```

Any ideas?  I am trying to do this without adding extra variables, but I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: `I need a set of numbers to increase from 2` Can you explain more ? you can put the expected output.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas  The expected output is below the problem.

Comment: I do some solution, let may know if it doesn't meet your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution without an additional variable, but...

...one with a closure:

```js
var getNext = (function(n) {
  var value = (typeof n !== "number" ? 2 : n);

  return function(i) {
    if (i === 0) return;

    console.log(i, value);
    value++;

    getNext(--i);
  }
}());
//}(5 /* <-- start value */));

getNext(3);
```

...and one with an additional parameter:

```js
function getNext(i, n) {
  if (i === 0) return;

  n = (typeof n !== "number" ? 2 : n);
  console.log(i, n);

  getNext(i - 1, n + 1);
}

getNext(3);
//getNext(3, 5 /* <-- start value */);
```

Both let you define a different start value if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can you another parameter for the value.

***Example:***

```js
function getNext(i, val) {
    if (i == 0) return;
    if (i === 3) {
        val = 2;
    } else {
        val++;
    }
    console.log("index: ", i, " value: ", val);
    i--;
    getNext(i, val);
}

getNext(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected output (logging in console) here is the code for you, but I have no idea what you will do with the log.

```
function getNext(i, x) {
var inc = x ? 2 : x;
    if(i == 0) return;
    console.log('index: ' + i + ', value: ' + inc);
    getNext(--i, ++inc);
}
```

and call it like `getNext(3)`